# Custom layout for Fading ActionBar Lib

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-library

I'm using Fading action bar library in my activity but i can't find a way to set a custom layout to the action bar .i can only set a drawable to my action bar in this library, i tried looking inside libraries code but it didn't help so much ............ is there anyway to do that.

here is how it usually works :

```
         FadingActionBarHelper helper = new FadingActionBarHelper()
        .actionBarBackground(R.drawable.ab_background)
        .headerLayout(R.layout.header)
        .contentLayout(R.layout.activity_profile);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, it works in my side

inflate your custom action bar

```
    final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.actionbar_layout,
            null);
```

config your action bar & setCustomView

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
```

then use FadingActionbar code

```
     FadingActionBarHelper helper = new FadingActionBarHelper()
    .actionBarBackground(R.drawable.ab_background)
    .headerLayout(R.layout.header)
    .contentLayout(R.layout.activity_profile);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a compatible version for FadingActionBar with the ActionBar Compat library. You can find it on https://github.com/felixWackernagel/FadingActionBar-Compat.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [this](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/) as [FadingActionBar](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar) mentiond. It's simple and you will understand how the library workds.